# Swapping file and directory names

Tags: command-line, files, batch-rename, filename

I have a collection of files at `./date-and-time/fixed/path/filename` where `date-and-time` and `filename` are variable. I would like to move all these files to `./filename/date-and-time`. The former path is the filename and the former filename is the path. Is there a good way to do this? There are ~1000 files in total with ~100 distinct filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work (note I have `echo`ed the actual commands; please check carefully that it is doing the right thing before removing them)

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for file in */fixed/path/*; do 
  [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
  f="${file##*/}"; d="${file%%/*}"
  echo mkdir -p "$f" && echo mv --no-clobber -- "$file" "$f/$d"
done
```

Comment: This worked perfectly once I switched from dash to bash. Thanks!

Comment: @Charles oops sorry I should have mentioned that - the `[[ ... ]]` in particular is bash-specific, although in this context `[ ... ]` should work in either shell

Comment: No worries, my fault for not specifying. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume the pattern for the path is always `./date-and-time/fixed/path/filename` with variable `date-and-time` and `filename`.

`date-and-time` can be extracted via `awk`:

```
$ echo './date-and-time/fixed/path/filename' |awk -F "/" '{print $2}'
date-and-time
```

`filename` is a bit easier to get as it can be extracted by `basename`:

```
$ basename ./date-and-time/fixed/path/filename
filename
```

From these two code segments, an untested script follows for moving the files in the way you describe when executed in `.`. Please verify it before use.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in ./*/fixed/path/*; do
    date_and_time=$(echo "$i" |awk -F "/" '{print $2}');
    filename=$(basename "$i");
    mkdir "$filename";
    mv "$i" "$filename"/"$date_and_time";
done;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
mkdir ./filename/ && mv ./date-and-time/path/to/path-to-your-folder/* ./filename/date-and-time
```

## **Edit**:

If you need to create more folders i recommend making a script something like this :

**Before you start, I really recommend you make a backup of the folder you are trying to do this on.**

cd into the folder you trying to operate on and then:

```
for file in *; do
  if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
    mkdir "${file%.*}"
    mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
  fi
done
```

1. Loop over all (*) the files in the current folder.
2. create a folder (mkdir) from the file without its extension ${file%.*}
3. move (mv) the file into that folder.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that I wouldn't have to enter 1000 times with different paths and filenames.

Comment: You got 1000 dif folders ? You can always use the * or do you need to create also 1000 new directory's ?

Comment: Then i recommend using a script. Edited my answer.